# $("a[rel='example1']").colorbox is not a function

Tags: jquery, wordpress, colorbox

I am have integrated the colorbox jQuery Plugin into the Wordpress theme.
But on the home page it displays
`$("a[rel='example1']").colorbox` is not a function

but when I am running the code on the inner pages its working fine.

Please help

Link to the website: http://lab.pixzon.com/ca

Below is the code for the header file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title><?php echo bloginfo('title');?></title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url')?>/images/icon.jpg"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="<?php echo bloginfo('stylesheet_url')?>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url')?>/css/colorbox.css" />
<script src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url')?>/colorbox/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url')?>/js/browcss.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url')?>/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url')?>/js/site.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url')?>/js/swfobject.js"></script>
<?php 
wp_head();
?>
```

Comment: Have you uploaded the ColorBox plugin? How are you linking to the file?

Comment: @codemaster is jquery and other plugin getting conflict?? can you try jquery non conflict

Comment: what is the exact error?

Comment: This question is pretty much unanswerable without any more information. We *could* produce a list of plausible reasons for you to troubleshoot, but why not just make it easy and actually show some code or a link to a sample site?

Comment: the problem is persisting on the home page of the website...

Comment: @codemaster mostly i think colorbox plugin is not avaible...for jquery??

Comment: this is the problem that is created on the home page only else its working fine everywhere

Comment: @gov it is available for jQuery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is, that you are loading two versions of jQuery.

What actually happens: you load the first jQuery, you then extend it with the Colorbox plugin and then you overwrite your first (extended) jQuery again. Just remove the last reference to jQuery and you should be good.

EDIT: looking at your code I suspect, that your `wp_head();` call is adding the second reference.

EDIT2: On the home page, the jQuery script is being reloaded in the body (inside the poll `div`)

Comment: @sbestform: If the problem has to persist then it should be the same on all the pages. But this problem is generated on the home page only not on any other page.

Comment: On the home page you are reloading the jquery script inside of the poll div.

Answer (score 1):

You can check you home page source:

Ex.

1. View the page source of your home page site.
2. Check if all dependencies of that code is included in the header / the code is either above to its dependencies.
   ex. One instance is jquery is not included in the home page.
      Are you using different javascript framework? if yes, then you need to put a Jquery no Conflict code.

Possible Reason:

One of the closest reason why is it not considered as a function because of dependencies missing.

Comment: Janzell: I have tried the no conflict code also and i am not using any other framework other JQuery.

Comment: I see. I guess Yi Jang is correct, `wp_head();` usually include a jquery library so, you're might loaded the jquery library twice which causing a conflict that's why your colorbox lib. is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

try to use jQuery in this form:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery("a[rel='example1']").colorbox
});
```

It should work.